# yii2 dynamic form updating only one table

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to update data with the help of yii2/dynamic form.
Table 1- "sellsg" - columns (ssg_id,ssg_customer,ssg_invoiceno,ssg_date,ssg_amount)
Table2 - "sellitemsg" - columns (ssgi_id,ssgi_invoiceno,ssgi_sgname,ssgi_price)

Relation - sellsg.ssg_invoiceno = sellitemsg.ssgi_invoiceno

The Create part is working fine. I'm struggling with the update part.
**Problem 1**. 
When the form was creating new record - There is a javascript code in the form to increase the invoice no by 1 everytime. When I'm loading the form for update, it also increases in by 1 overriding the original invoiceno. I want to limit this function only when I create but not in update.

**Problem 2**
When I am updating the form, it only updating the sellsg table but not sellitemsg table.

_Form

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use frontend\modules\sellsg\models\Customer;
use frontend\modules\sellsg\models\Sunglass;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\sellsg\models\Sellsg */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="sellsg-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'dynamic-form',
        'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
        'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 3, 'deviceSize' => ActiveForm::SIZE_SMALL]
        ]); 
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'ssg_customer')->label(false)->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Customer::find()->all(),'c_name','customerDetails'),
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Customer Details', 'id' => 'custid'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'allowClear' => true
                        ],
                        ]); 
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'ssg_date')->widget(
                    DatePicker::className(), [
                    // inline too, not bad
                     'inline' => false,

                     // modify template for custom rendering
                    //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,

                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                    ]);?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ssg_invoiceno')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="rows">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Sunglasses</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
             <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 20, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsSellitemsg[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'ssgi_sgname',
                    'ssgi_price',
                ],
            ]); ?>

            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsSellitemsg as $i => $modelSellitemsg): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelSellitemsg->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelSellitemsg, "[{$i}]ssgi_id");
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelSellitemsg, "[{$i}]ssgi_sgname")->label(false)->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Sunglass::find()->all(),'sg_name','sg_name'),
                                    'language' => 'en',
                                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Sunglass'],
                                    'pluginOptions' => [
                                        'allowClear' => true
                                    ],
                                    ]); 
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <?= $form->field($modelSellitemsg, "[{$i}]ssgi_price")->textInput([
                                'maxlength' => true,
                                'class' => 'sumPart',
                                //'onfocus'=>'sum()', 'onBlur'=>'sum()'
                                ]) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .row -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'ssg_amount')->textInput(['class' => 'sum']) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<?php
/* start getting the invoiceno */
$script = <<<EOD
  $(window).load(function(){
  $.get('get-for-invoiceno',{ invoiceid : 1 }, function(data){
      //alert(data);
      var data = $.parseJSON(data);
      $('#sellsg-ssg_invoiceno').attr('value',data.invoiceno);
  }
  );
});
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the invoiceno */
?>

<?php
/* start getting the totalamount */
$script = <<<EOD
    var getSum = function() {

        var items = $(".item");
        var sum = 0;

        items.each(function (index, elem) {
            var priceValue = $(elem).find(".sumPart").val();
            //Check if priceValue is numeric or something like that
            sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(priceValue);
        });
        //Assign the sum value to the field
        $(".sum").val(sum);
    };

    //Bind new elements to support the function too
    $(".container-items").on("change", ".sumPart", function() {
        getSum();
    });
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the totalamount */
?>
```

SellsgController

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Sellsg();
        $modelsSellitemsg = [new Sellitemsg];

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            $modelsSellitemsg = Model::createMultiple(Sellitemsg::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsSellitemsg, Yii::$app->request->post());

            // validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsSellitemsg) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelsSellitemsg as $modelSellitemsg) {
                            $modelSellitemsg->ssgi_invoiceno = $model->ssg_invoiceno;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelSellitemsg->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ssg_id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsSellitemsg' => (empty($modelsSellitemsg)) ? [new Sellitemsg] : $modelsSellitemsg
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Sellsg model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $modelsSellitemsg = $model->sellitemsg;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsSellitemsg, 'id', 'id');
            //var_dump($oldIDs);
            $modelsSellitemsg = Model::createMultiple(Sellitemsg::classname(), $modelsSellitemsg);
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsSellitemsg, Yii::$app->request->post());
            $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsSellitemsg, 'id', 'id')));

            // validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsSellitemsg) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        if (! empty($deletedIDs)) {
                            Sellitemsg::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                        }
                        foreach ($modelsSellitemsg as $modelSellitemsg) {
                            $modelSellitemsg->ssgi_invoiceno = $model->ssg_invoiceno;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelSellitemsg->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ssg_id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsSellitemsg' => (empty($modelsSellitemsg)) ? [new Sellitemsg] : $modelsSellitemsg
            ]);
        }
    }
```

sellsg model

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\sellsg\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "sellsg".
 *
 * @property integer $ssg_id
 * @property string $ssg_customer
 * @property integer $ssg_invoiceno
 * @property string $ssg_date
 * @property integer $ssg_amount
 */
class Sellsg extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $modelsSellitemsg;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'sellsg';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['ssg_customer', 'ssg_invoiceno', 'ssg_date', 'ssg_amount'], 'required'],
            [['ssg_invoiceno', 'ssg_amount'], 'integer'],
            [['ssg_customer'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
            [['ssg_invoiceno'], 'unique'],
            [['ssg_date'], 'string', 'max' => 10], 
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'ssg_id' => 'ID',
            'ssg_customer' => 'Customer',
            'ssg_invoiceno' => 'Invoice No',
            'ssg_date' => 'Date',
            'ssg_amount' => 'Amount',
        ];
    }
    public function getSellitemsg()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Sellitemsg::className(), ['ssgi_invoiceno' => 'ssg_invoiceno']);
        }
}
```

update.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\sellsg\models\Sellsg */

$this->title = 'Update Sellsg: ' . $model->ssg_id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Sellsgs', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $model->ssg_id, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $model->ssg_id]];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = 'Update';
?>
<div class="sellsg-update">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsSellitemsg' => $modelsSellitemsg,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

With the current code I'm getting error

```
Getting unknown property: frontend\modules\sellsg\models\Sellitemsg::id
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe we should use some communication service (like email or something similar) because you're posting a lot of questions recently and most likely the majority is still not solved yet.

Comment: Many have been solved. Few pending. I'm a beginner in this field. So lots of questions. I like this service though. Many helpful persons around.

Comment: I see, my bad, I thought none were solved. Well, I currently don't have time but I may take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution

**Problem1** -
I've created `_updateform.php` and redirected to update from there and removed the javascript to load invoicno -
Update.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\sellsg\models\Sellsg */

$this->title = 'Update InvoiceNo: ' . $model->ssg_id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Sellsgs', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $model->ssg_id, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $model->ssg_id]];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = 'Update';
?>
<div class="sellsg-update">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_updateform', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsSellitemsg' => $modelsSellitemsg,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

**Problem2**
My actionUpdate code now looks like -

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $modelsSellitemsg = $model->sellitemsg;
        //$model->setScenario('update');

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsSellitemsg, 'ssgi_id', 'ssgi_id');
            //var_dump($oldIDs);
            $modelsSellitemsg = Model::createMultiple(Sellitemsg::classname(), $modelsSellitemsg);
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsSellitemsg, Yii::$app->request->post());
            $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsSellitemsg, 'ssgi_id', 'ssgi_id')));

            // validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsSellitemsg) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        if (! empty($deletedIDs)) {
                            Sellitemsg::deleteAll(['ssgi_id' => $deletedIDs]);
                        }
                        foreach ($modelsSellitemsg as $modelSellitemsg) {
                            $modelSellitemsg->ssgi_invoiceno = $model->ssg_invoiceno;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelSellitemsg->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ssg_id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsSellitemsg' => (empty($modelsSellitemsg)) ? [new Sellitemsg] : $modelsSellitemsg
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Sellsg model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

and Model.php -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\sellsg\models;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class Model extends \yii\base\Model
{
    /**
     * Creates and populates a set of models.
     *
     * @param string $modelClass
     * @param array $multipleModels
     * @return array
     */
    public static function createMultiple($modelClass, $multipleModels = [])
    {
        $model    = new $modelClass;
        $formName = $model->formName();
        $post     = Yii::$app->request->post($formName);
        $models   = [];

        if (! empty($multipleModels)) {
            $keys = array_keys(ArrayHelper::map($multipleModels, 'ssgi_id', 'ssgi_id'));
            $multipleModels = array_combine($keys, $multipleModels);
        }

        if ($post && is_array($post)) {
            foreach ($post as $i => $item) {
                if (isset($item['ssgi_id']) && !empty($item['ssgi_id']) && isset($multipleModels[$item['ssgi_id']])) {
                    $models[] = $multipleModels[$item['ssgi_id']];
                } else {
                    $models[] = new $modelClass;
                }
            }
        }

        unset($model, $formName, $post);

        return $models;
    }
}
```

And Is working fine now.